# Order Array in Array Recursive PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, sorting, recursive-datastructures

[This is my DB table IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Kwg.png)

1. I Have This code but, the result is this:

   array:2 [▼
     3 => array:1 [▼
       1 => []
     ]
     4 => array:1 [▼
       5 => array:1 [▼
         6 => array:1 [▼
           7 => []
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ]
2. But i need organize the code like this:

   array:[

   0 => 3,
   1 => 1,
   2 => 4,
   3 => 5,
   4 => 6,
   5 => 7

   ]

```
// actually the parameter id is the session user

    public function misSubordinados($id){

    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $sql = 'SELECT s.id_usuario  FROM `sy_supervisores_asesor` AS s
            WHERE s.id_supervisor IN (' . implode(',', [$id]) . ')';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $total = array();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(count($result) > 0) {

        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                $total[$value['id_usuario']] = $this->misSubordinados($value['id_usuario']);  
        }

    }

    return $total;

    }
```

Comment: Then why are you calling this function recursively? Just do `$total[$value['id_usuario']] = $value['id_usuario'];` instead of `$total[$value['id_usuario']] = $this->misSubordinados($value['id_usuario']);`

Comment: Because i have a table parent children, but that children have childrens, and i need the id´s of the hierarchy.

Comment: iam very curious how the table data looks like.. And what MySQL version you are using..

Comment: Then I guess it will be a better approach handling this in one MySQL query instead. Show us your table structure with some dummy data.

Comment: The table is up, for example if my user is id_supervisor 2 show me all the id_usuarios rows and then show me the id_usuarios from that children rows

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Give me an input & output example

Comment: for example i have the $id = 2; and the output is $result = array[3,4] and the next the recursive search make the iteration and this  found the records with the id 3 and 4 etc.

Comment: i got it, thanks.

            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                $total[] = $value['id_usuario'];
                $total = array_merge($total,$this->misSubordinados($value['id_usuario']));

            }